# German residency with remote employer?

Tags: working-visas, germany, working

I'm looking to move to Germany. I currently work for a remote U.S.-based employer with no meaningful connections to Germany. Is there a visa that works for me? I don't fit the freelancer category, but I also am not looking to work for a German employer. I work in IT if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, freelancer is the only option.  If your employer isn't willing to pay you as a contractor, I don't think you'll be able to move to Germany without finding a different employer.

Comment: A business visa, but starting your own company without already having German residence might be a real challenge.

Comment: If you work as a remote-only worker then moving to Germany might not be that good a choice as your tax burdens will be high, not to mention if you have no previous experience living there. Unless you have some other reasons for moving to Germany of course.